# What are the best websites for free tikz diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use already created `TikZ` drawings.

Are there websites where I can find such resources? What are the best ones?

Comment: You can see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf

Answer (score 3):

[TikZ and PGF examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), [PGFPlots examples](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/), [PGFPlots Gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)
[TeX StackExchange Questions tagged 'tikz-pgf'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf)